# Export-CRMSolution Loop Failing ? (Microsoft.Xrm.Data.PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, dynamics-crm, crm, power-automate

I'm trying to export all Power Automate solutions. Export-CrmSolution works one at a time, but breaks when I try to make it loop through the solution names. I've tried putting them into an array, putting the variable in quotes and parentheses, and making sure it is formatted as a string.
Totally new to this module, so any help greatly appreciated!

```
$allSolutions = (Get-CrmRecords -EntityLogicalName solution -Fields *)

foreach($solution in $allSolutions)
    {
       $solutionname = $Solution.CrmRecords.friendlyname | Out-String
       Export-CrmSolution -SolutionName $solutionname
       
    }
```

Error:

```
Get-CrmRecordsByFetch : System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: ************ FaultException`1 - RetrieveMultiple : GetEntityDataByFetchSearch |=>  Sql error: A validation error occurred. A string value provided is too long. CRM ErrorCode: -2147012607 Sql ErrorCode: -2146232060 Sql Number: 8152
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fun Fact: Solved it. Thanks!

1. String Too Long?
   Filter to only visible solutions.
   Ex.

   Where-Object{ $_.isvisible -eq "yes"}
2. Can't find solution by "Name"?
   It wants the record's UniqueName, not FriendlyName.
   Ex.

   Export-CrmSolution "$($solution.uniquename)"

Boom, it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).